What is the punishment for drinking alcohol after 3 times?
It is narrated in https://sunnah.com/nasai:5661:

"The Messenger of Allah [SAW] said: 'Whoever drinks Khamr, whip him; then if he drinks (again), whip him; then if he drinks (again), whip him; then if he drinks (again), kill him.'"

It is narrated in https://sunnah.com/abudawud:4485:

The Prophet (ﷺ) said: If anyone drinks wine, flog him; if he repeats it, flog him, and if he repeats it, flog him. If he does it again a third or a fourth time, kill him. A man who had drunk wine was brought (to him) and he gave him lashes. He was again brought to him, and he flogged him. He was again brought to him and he flogged him. He was again brought to him and he flogged him. The punishment of killing (for drinking) was repealed, and a concession was allowed.

According to the jamahir (masses), the second hadith had abrogated the first hadith, however, according to the contemporary scholar Ahmad Shakir, there is a problem with this Hadith. Qabisah ibn Dhuwaib was two years old when Muhammad died. It is impossible that he heard this from Muhammad. Thus, this Hadith was regarded as Daif by Al-Albani. However, Shu’ayb Arna’ut was willing to, without evidence, presume that Qabisah heard it from a Companion of Muhammad so declared it Sahih. As-Sindi said that there are some ten hadiths, all of which are sahih and explicit about killing in the fourth instance. There is nothing that explicitly counters it. The statement of those who say that it has been abrogated is not backed by any proof. Likewise, Ibn Taymiyyah said that it is a tazeer that an imam makes when necessary.
I find the arguments of Ahmad Shakir and co to be convincing, however, it seems that the jamahir advocated the position that such a punishment was abrogated. Is there any proof to substantiate their claims alongside a counter to the claims of the following contemporaries above?

Yes it does, thank you!
